# "HTTP Error 404, The requested resource is not found" but Tomcat has started successfully

Tags: java, tomcat

I am able to run tomcat 7.0.41 and getting below message in the console :

```
"INFO: Server startup in 9393 ms"
```

[Tomcat Console Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNWvl.png)

When I am trying to open http://localhost:8080/,
 I am getting the following error message :

```
Not Found

HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
```

I have already checked my conf/server.xml file and it is:

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"...
```

I hope you will help me to find out where is the issue.

Comment: Do you have a ROOT in your webapps directory?

Comment: How you have started your tomcat?

Comment: I had a project there but I deleted it. Now it's an empty directory

Comment: Hey Black Swan, I started Tomcat by double click on startup.bat

Comment: Are other links working, like http://localhost:8080/docs/?

Comment: @BlackSwan other links are not working either

Comment: What deployed modules (like /docs) do you have present under `webapps` folder? If `webapps` is empty you have no deployments at all. Looks like you have something called `Peers-Review-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` which means you should be hitting http://localhost:8080/Peers-Review-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ in the browser